# Wicket: Ajax post with success flag

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, wicket

I need to post data to the server (java) and get a response back if everything was successful. How can I achieve this because this call needs to be synchronous?

I was using Wicket.Ajax.post and added behavior with corresponding callback, but I only succeeded to post the data, and not to get the response back from the server on the JavaScript side where I will process if success was true or not.

Comment: Can you post some code? I think you might use one of the ajax call listener that can be passed as attribute to post function. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Wicket+Ajax

Comment: Check https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/guide/ajax.html#ajax_5. You need to provide 'sh', i.e. success handler.